# how can i pass the value of <a> tag form ui-serf to the url in the state provider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/peERl4?p=preview) to explain my question:

In the index.html when i click on this link

```
<li><a ui-sref="route1({test:true})">Route 1</a></li>
```

It goes to this link :   `http://localhost:3000/#/route1?test=true`

I'm trying to figure out how I can grab the text "Route 1" from the a link and use it as an parameter in the route 
            url: "/route1:?test",

i want the url to be generated dynamically like:    url: "/route1:Route 1"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for - I looked at the plunkr and you code is technically correct as far as syntax. are you saying you want the url to be `host.com/#/route1/route1` ? or are you saying you want the url is correct as is and you want the inner text on the `<a>` tag to be in scope and passed to the state?

Comment: yes to the second one.     if there is a link                         <li><a ui-sref="route1">abc</a></li>     .  when somebody clicks on this link, it should go to the state                                       .state('route1', {
     url: "/route1:abc",      
     templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can make the route name part of your state params part of your params,

1. You can make it part of your state (such as `/:routename/?test`, you can make it part of the resolve property on your state definition **[see here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)**
2. You can append it to the route - however as you have it in your example, your text `Route 1` is not bound to a scope or even  put in angular, so you would need to *at the very least* add it to scope - using either handlebars (i.e.`{{ routeName }}` and setting the value in the controller) or make the value mapped in a config somewhere and inject it into the controller.

I think if you want to rely upon it the same way you can rely upon the URL params, I would suggest taking a look at the resolve object in your route definitions, as it seems to be what you are looking for.

You would need to define the actual text outside the resolve map though, and maybe make a function that returned the value from a config module, so that way you can also bind the value to the navbar link.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1?test",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        resolve: {
             activeRoute: function () {
                 //you could have a config map that you inject into this module
                 //or have it be a set property
                 return myConfigMap['route1'];
             }
        }
    })
      [...]
```

3. You could use the custom data, **[see here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)**, which could then be accessed like this in your controller:

   ```
   console.log($state.current.data.customData1);
   ```

No matter what it has to be defined somehow, if you want truly dynamic url generation, you might need to build a function that could build state definitions based on a list of parameters that define that particular state.